# Geo distance based sorting in Elasticsearch 2.3 stopped working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have implemented search and sorting of users in Elasticsearch based on their location. It used to work fine in Elasticsearch 1.6, but after upgrading to Elasticsearch 2.3.3 it stopped working.

This is my mapping in ES:

```
{
"user": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "store": false,
            "type": "long"
        },
        "url": {
            "store": false,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "store": false,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastname": {
            "store": false,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "system": {
            "store": false,
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "avatar": {
            "store": false,
            "type": "string"
        },

        "position": {
            "store": false,
            "type": "string"
        },

        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        },


        "roles": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "store": false,
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        },

        "credentials": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "store": false,
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "progress": {
                    "store": false,
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "instructorId": {
                    "store": false,
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "dateEnrolled":{
                    "store": false,
                    "type":"date",
                    "format":"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
                }
            }
        },
        "credentialsWithInstructorRole": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "store": false,
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "dateAssigned":{
                    "store": false,
                    "type":"date",
                    "format":"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I try to execute the following query directly it works fine:

```
[
      {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 3,
        "query": {
          "bool": {
        "must_not": {
          "term": {
            "id": 2
          }
        },
        "should": {
          "match_all": {}
        }
          }
        },
        "sort": [
          {
        "_geo_distance": {
          "user.location": [
            {
              "lat": 49.2827291,
              "lon": -123.12073750000002
            }
          ],
          "unit": "km"
        }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

However, when the same query is executed using Java API, there is an exception:

```
Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[G88txaRXQESUgytUEnTwug][users_zj][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Living Colossus][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":3,"query":{"bool":{"must_not":{"term":{"id":2}},"should":{"match_all":{}}}},"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"user.location":[{"lat":49.2827291,"lon":-123.12073750000002}],"unit":"km"}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[G88txaRXQESUgytUEnTwug][users_zj][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Living Colossus][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":3,"query":{"bool":{"must_not":{"term":{"id":2}},"should":{"match_all":{}}}},"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"user.location":[{"lat":49.2827291,"lon":-123.12073750000002}],"unit":"km"}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[G88txaRXQESUgytUEnTwug][users_zj][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Living Colossus][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":3,"query":{"bool":{"must_not":{"term":{"id":2}},"should":{"match_all":{}}}},"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"user.location":[{"lat":49.2827291,"lon":-123.12073750000002}],"unit":"km"}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[G88txaRXQESUgytUEnTwug][users_zj][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Living Colossus][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":3,"query":{"bool":{"must_not":{"term":{"id":2}},"should":{"match_all":{}}}},"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"user.location":[{"lat":49.2827291,"lon":-123.12073750000002}],"unit":"km"}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[G88txaRXQESUgytUEnTwug][users_zj][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Living Colossus][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":3,"query":{"bool":{"must_not":{"term":{"id":2}},"should":{"match_all":{}}}},"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"user.location":[{"lat":49.2827291,"lon":-123.12073750000002}],"unit":"km"}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort]; }
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:206)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$1.onFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:152)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:855)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:833)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.onFailure(TransportService.java:387)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:39)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[: failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort];
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.guessRootCauses(ElasticsearchException.java:386)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.guessRootCauses(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:152)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.getCause(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:99)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.writeTo(ElasticsearchException.java:226)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.writeTo(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeThrowable(StreamOutput.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.writeTo(ElasticsearchException.java:226)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.ActionTransportException.writeTo(ActionTransportException.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeThrowable(StreamOutput.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransportChannel.sendResponse(NettyTransportChannel.java:120)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.DelegatingTransportChannel.sendResponse(DelegatingTransportChannel.java:68)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry$TransportChannelWrapper.sendResponse(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:146)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler$1.onFailure(HandledTransportAction.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.raiseEarlyFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:294)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to find mapper for [user.location] for geo distance based sort
        at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.GeoDistanceSortParser.parse(GeoDistanceSortParser.java:161)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortParseElement.addCompoundSortField(SortParseElement.java:141)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortParseElement.parse(SortParseElement.java:84)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:838)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:654)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:620)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:371)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        ... 3 more
```

This is java method that fires exception:

```
    @Override
public List<User> getCollaboratorsBasedOnLocation(Collection<User> ignoredUsers, double lat, double lon, int limit){
    List<User> foundUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        Client client = ElasticSearchFactory.getClient();
        QueryBuilder qb = new MatchAllQueryBuilder();
        BoolQueryBuilder bQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        bQueryBuilder.should(qb);

        for (User ignUser : ignoredUsers) {
            if (ignUser != null) {
                bQueryBuilder.mustNot(termQuery("id", ignUser.getId()));
            }
        }
        GeoDistanceSortBuilder sortBuilder = SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort("user.location")
                .point(lat, lon)
                .unit(DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS)
                .order(SortOrder.ASC);

        SearchResponse sResponse = client
                .prepareSearch(ESIndexNames.INDEX_USERS)
                .setTypes(ESIndexTypes.USER)
                .setQuery(bQueryBuilder)
                .addSort(sortBuilder)
                .setFrom(0)
                .setSize(limit)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        foundUsers = this.convertSearchResponseToUsersList(sResponse);
    } catch (NoNodeAvailableException e1) {
        logger.error(e1);
    }
    return foundUsers;
}
```

**Solution**

It turned out that the problem was in the path in my sort part of the algorithm. It was not correct and after changing "user.location" to "location" everything started to work fine again.

Comment: Against which indices are you running the queries in both cases (manual query, java code)?

Comment: In both cases, I was using the same index. I've edited my question to include java source code that triggers exception.

Comment: What is the mapping for the `users_zj` index and, specifically, the `user.location` field?

Comment: Mapping is the same as I posted in the question. That is from my mapping json file, but index has exactly the same mapping, except there is no "store" attributes.